# Cannot find "Enable Email Drafts" in support settings

Tags: service-cloud-console

I have to send emails from Salesforce. But there is some custom field on EmailMessage that I need to populate first and then send the email. Therefore, I am inserting EmailMessage record first and then using Messaging.sendEmailMessage() (which takes ids of the EmailMessage records) sending the emails. When executing this method I am getting 'Draft Email not enabled' error message.

In the a help article (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=case_interaction_enabling_email_drafts.htm&type=5), its mentioned that we can enable this from Support Settings in setup but I am not able to find this in support settings. Is it moved to some other section in Setup? Please help me find this config to enable draft email. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to activate the Enable Case Feed Actions and Feed Items in Support Settings to see this option.

Comment: Please include the link to the relevant Salesforce documentation in your answer. See [answer]